# How to bootstrap certificates for LCM to reference for signatureverification settings?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, dsc, azure-automation

WMF 5.1 includes new functionality to allow signing of MOF documents and DSC Resource modules ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/dsc-improvements#dsc-module-and-configuration-signing-validations)).  However, this seems very difficult to implement in reality -- or I'm making it more complicated than it is...

My scenario is VMs in Azure and I'd like to leverage Azure Automation for Pull DSC Server; however, I see this applying on premise too.  The problem is that the certificate used to sign the MOF configurations and/or modules needs to get placed on the machine ***before*** fetching and applying the configuration otherwise configuration will fail because the certificate isn't trusted or present on the machine.

I tried using Azure KeyVault to bootstrap the certificate (just the public key because that's my understanding of how signing works) and that fails using `Add-AzureRmVMSecret` because the `CertificateUrl` parameter expects a full certificate with the public/private key pair to install.  In an ideal world, this would be the solution but that's not the case...

Other ideas, again in this context, would be to upload the cert to blob storage, use a CustomScriptExtension to pull down the cert and install into the LocalMachine store but that feels nasty as well because, ideally, that script should be signed as well and that puts us back in the same spot.

I suppose another idea would be to first PUSH a configuration that downloaded and installed certificates only but that doesn't sound great either.

Last option would be to rely on an AD GPO or something similar to potentially push the certificate first...but, honestly, trying to move away from much of that if/when possible...

Am I off-base on this? It seems like this should be a solvable problem -- just looking for at least one "good" way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

David Jones has quite a bit of experiencing dealing with this issue in an on-premises environment, but as you stated the same concepts should apply for Azure.   [Here](https://powershell.org/2017/04/21/colecting-certificates-form-an-enterprise-ca-for-use-with-dsc/) is a link to his blog.  [This](https://github.com/BladeFireLight/PKITools) is a link to his GitHub site with a PKITools module that he created.  If all else fails you can reach out to him on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/BladeFireLight).

Answer (score 0):

While it's quite easy to populate a pre-booted image with public certificates. it's not possible (that I have found) to populate the private key.

DSC would require the private key to decrypt the passwords.

The most common tactic people blog about is to use the unattend to script the import of a PFX. issue there is you have to leave the password for the PFX in plain text. Perhaps that is ok in your environment.

The other option requires a more complicated setup. Use a simple DSC or GPO to auto enroll a unique certificate. then have the system, via first boot script or DSC custom resource, tickle an API (Like Polaris) and that triggers a DSC script that uses PKITools or other script to get the public certificate that the machine has. Then have that API push a new DSC config (or pull settings) to the machine.

Comment: Theoretically you would use TUG to issue chained DSC config so the first one enrolls and when TUG detects the machine in question had it's certificate it switches scripts. But I have little experience with TUG.